# localhost http 500 internal server error stripe react

Tags: reactjs, localhost, stripe-payments, yarnpkg

I try to use stripe in my LocalHost, but when I post a request to stripe server, I've got this error :

> POST https://localhost:3000/charge 500 (Internal Server Error)

But, on the stripe dashboard, the request have 200 return code. In accord with the support, the problem come from my localhost, but I don't have a idea ...
I have just follow this tutorial : https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react#setup

Thanks !

Comment: If you're using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react#create-charge) example then the 500 is returned if there was an exception(line 12). Add a `console.log(err)` there, and check your [Stripe logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, it's work.

This is why it's work now :
If you are on windows, install BashUbuntu, and make all command in bashUbuntu !

Answer (score -1):

First have a look at the access log. 500 error indicates that your front end has some problems talking to the back end, though the TCP port itself and HTTPD server are alive. In the access log (location depends on your OS) you will see the error. Then you will make further steps.

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your response.
But when I check error log, I've got nothing in :(